# Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, node.js, foreach, ejs

I have a problem in these line of codes i think

```
app.post('/delete/:id',(req,res)=>{
    db.execute(`DELETE FROM 'tabel' WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`)
    res.redirect('/')
})
```

when i try to delete something it gives me the '42S22' state and ive got an error everytime i try it. This is how my form in Ejs looks like

```
<% data.forEach(row=>{ %>
        <form action="/delete/<%= row.id %>" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="X">
        </form>
    <% }) %>
```

this code is coded in Nodejs and MySql!

I have tried on youtube and in google searching but i couldn't get the right answer so i hope i will get the right answer here by my fella colleges!

Comment: Provide your `table` schema.

Comment: NAME: id TYPE: int255 NULL: no EXTRA: AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of issues with your code.

First, you're using single quotes to enclose the table name in your `DELETE` statement, but you should be using backticks (`) instead. Single quotes are used to enclose string values in SQL, but backticks are used to enclose table and column names.

Second, you're using the `params` property of the `req` object to access the `id` parameter in your route, but this property is used to access parameters in the route path itself. So if your route is defined as `/delete/:id`, you can access the `id` parameter using `req.params.id`. However, if your `id` parameter is being passed as a query string or as part of the request body, you'll need to use a different property of the `req` object to access it. For example, if the `id` parameter is being passed as a query string, you can access it using req.query.id.

Here's how your code might look with these changes applied:

```
app.post('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
  db.execute(`DELETE FROM \`tabel\` WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`)
  res.redirect('/')
})
```

However, this code is still vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, because you're using string interpolation to construct your SQL query. Instead, you should use parameterized queries to avoid this issue.

Here's an example of how you could rewrite your code using parameterized queries:

```
app.post('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
  db.execute(`DELETE FROM \`tabel\` WHERE id = ?`, [req.params.id])
  res.redirect('/')
})
```

In this example, I've replaced the string interpolation with a `?` placeholder, and I've passed the `id` value as an additional argument to the `execute` method. This allows the database driver to properly escape the `id` value and prevent SQL injection attacks.